# make a raster from dataset (csv)

Tags: raster, r, csv

I was trying to make a raster from an dataset (https://www.dropbox.com/s/jsm1x06lnzfbqty/data.csv?dl=0)
code:

```
inter1= read.table("c:/data.csv", header=TRUE)
#convert to spatial points
coordinates(inter1) = ~long + lat
#gridify your set of points
gridded(inter1) <- TRUE 
#convert to raster
r <- raster(inter1)
#plot
plot(r)
```

I get as an error:

```
suggested tolerance minimum: 0.0487805 
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think you probably have a set of irregularly spaced points. That is, your points deviate from a regular spacing by more than the allowable tolerance. You need to interpolate the points onto a grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the script is expecting to read in a set of regularly spaced points, with deviations less than the minimum tolerance. Your set of points is actually quite irregularly spaced:

[image]

You can see that there are large missing areas. Also, if you zoom in closer, you'll see that even at the fine scale, the points are not regularly spaced on a grid structure:

[image]